# How to decide if I need global optimization

Tags: matlab, optimization, least-squares

I am performing some non-linear least-squares curve fitting. I came across global optimization tools and I am wondering if I should always use that. Is there something I should check before resorting to these advanced methods?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. When you do your curve-fitting using standard least-squares approaches (I.e., Levenberg-Marquardt, Gauss-Newton, etc...), is your fit acceptable? If the answer is “yes”, then there’s no point in using global optimization algorithms.

On the other hand, if the fit is very difficult and you’re coming up with ridiculous results, then you may have to resort to global solvers. However, depending on the size (number of variables) or your problem, you may not be able to get any better answer: for large problems, derivative-free algorithms are basically limited unless your objective function is extremely fast to evaluate and you’re allowing millions of function evaluations.

Since you haven’t said anything about your problem it’s difficult to give a meaningful suggestion. Are you able to provide the jacobian of your objective function? If you can, I would probably experiment first with a multi-start Levenberg-Marquardt, I have had good results with this approach. But you really need to provide more details...